# Unexpected realloc() behaviour

Tags: c, realloc

As part of a larger program, I have a method which computes the coefficients of the derivative of a polynomial. But that's not the problem:). In the following code, if I skip the realloc() call, I get the results I expect in (*coef). With the realloc one of the elements is set to 0. Is this my fault, or is the realloc() behaviour actually unexpected?

```
void derive (double **coef, int size)
{
    int i;
    if (size<2)
        free_vector (*coef);
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<size-1; ++i)
        {
            (*coef)[i] = (*coef)[i+1]*(i+1);
        }
        (*coef) = realloc ((*coef), size-1);
    }   
}
```

I'll also attach the complete source code for a test program if running it would help...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double *new_vector (int size)
{
    double *vec = calloc (size, sizeof (double));
    return vec;
}

void free_vector (double *vec)
{
    if (vec)
    {
        free (vec);
        vec = NULL;
    }
}

void write_vector (FILE *f, double *vec, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; ++i)
        fprintf (f, "%1.15lf\n", vec[i]);
    fprintf (f, "\n");
}

void derive (double **coef, int size)
{
    int i;
    if (size<2)
        free_vector (*coef);
    else
    {
        for (i=0; i<size-1; ++i)
        {
            (*coef)[i] = (*coef)[i+1]*(i+1);
        }
        (*coef) = realloc ((*coef), size-1);
    }   
}

int main (void)
{
    double *v = new_vector (5);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; ++i)
        v[i] = 3;
    write_vector (stdout, v, 5);
    derive (&v, 5);
    write_vector (stdout, v, 4);
    free_vector (v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you posted incomplete code - there's no realloc and no off-by-one in what you've shown.

Comment: @Erik: All the code was there. It was just formatted incorrectly using `<code>` and `<pre>` tags. I was editing to fix it, but N 1.1 beat me to it.

Comment: it was due to poor editing, thx for doing it before i managed to do it.Edit:I was beaten as well

Comment: I suspect you're writing past the end of the allocated array and thereby invoking undefined behavior. A degree `N` polynomial is an `N+1` element array.

Comment: Please remember that realloc( ) is always allowed to return a NULL pointer and I don't see that you taking care of that case, which you absolutely must: it's a well-known source of mem leaks if you don't.

Comment: Erik is right, my bad, the post is too large for the problem. Thank you for the coding tip, but that was not my worry here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realloc takes a number of bytes.

```
realloc ((*coef), (size-1) * sizeof(double));
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thank you, I just read that in man, but I wasn't able to apply it to my own code